# Reproducir video desde Google drive en HTML

Tags: video, google-drive, href

Tengo todo el permiso en Drive, se visualiza el thumbnail pero no logro escribir la URL correcta para reproducir el vídeo en mi HTML5.

Ésta es la URL del thumbnail que funciona bien en el poster del video

```
https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1SV001my3nyU22DDBkcLR-UYA0l_jV1C8
```

Y ésta es la URL del video que trato de reproducir

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SV001my3nyU22DDBkcLR-UYA0l_jV1C8/view?usp=sharing
```

```html
<video id="yoVideo" poster="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1SV001my3nyU22DDBkcLR-UYA0l_jV1C8" preload="auto" controls>
    <source src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SV001my3nyU22DDBkcLR-UYA0l_jV1C8/view?usp=sharing">
</video>
```

No puedo usar iFrame porque uso la etiqueta video directamente en mi reproductor HTML

Comment: Acá explican a profundidad el problema y posibles soluciones de usar el tag video con Google Drive. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52397246/15298643

Comment: El problema es que estas poniendo la url directamente del Google drive  y necesitas una url .mp4 o .webm. Creo que la solución seria poder bajar el video y publicarlo en un servidor web donde podrías hacer al video con el formato correcto.

Comment: Según en varias partes de internet tu URL debería de ser `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SV001my3nyU22DDBkcLR-UYA0l_jV1C8/preview` y he intentado realizar pruebas con tu video o un video propio sin tener resultado, la otra alternativa como ya te respondieron es utilizar `iframe`, igual te podría interesar leer las diferencias entre [Video y Iframe](https://support.splashthat.com/hc/en-us/articles/360037963911-What-s-the-difference-between-Iframe-elements-and-Video-elements)

Comment: Que formato es el video, podria que la biblioteca que utilizas este desactualizada, a mi da esos errores en la reproducción, ya que algunas plataformas usan codec especificos, que otras no tienen en sus librerias. Si tienes un video que deseas utilizar, busca guardarlo en diferentes formatos, y subelo o pruebalos desde los navegadores mas conocidos.

Comment: si le haces request a tu archivo `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1SV001my3nyU22DDBkcLR-UYA0l_jV1C8` pide que tengas un token, vas a tener que manejarlo con un backend porque todos los videos del drive son privados y estas autorizando que a cualesquiera que entre a tu url de drive y tenga una cuenta google pueda ver el video desde ahi.. no es que cualquiera tenga acceso, estan excluidas las peticiones que no sean desde navegador

Comment: Hay otra plataforma gratis o similar a Google drive que no sea complicado para usar como base de datos ?

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de video es el que carga la url?, yo no lo pude abrir.

Comment: Es mp4, @Jorgesys. Solamente uso el formato mp4. Con el iFrame funciona correctamente, pero no es lo que necesito, desconfigura todo el funcionamiento de mi reproductor

Comment: Te comento que alguna de las respuestas te podría funcionar, pero enfrentarías otro problema, las url del tipo descarga o preview de google drive funcionan de buenas a primeras, pero si una pagina tiene mucha concurrencia, ya que las peticiones de resolución se realizan desde el servidor y no desde el cliente, bloquearía temporalmente la resolución de la url desde la pagina en la que la coloques, esto solo pasa si las peticiones son muchas (por una ip), no se números exactos, me paso con imágenes alojadas en drive para una pagina que dejaron de mostrarse, espero este comentario sea de ayuda.

Comment: Ninguna de las respuestas me funciona (exepto el de iFrame que no puedo usar, porque como en mi pregunta necesito reproducir en la etiqueta video ). Para no dejar está pregunta pendiente, voy aceptar uno de ellos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probaste con el iframe que te dá Google cuando seleccionas `Embed item`?

Cuando intento colocarlo en la respuesta de S.O. no funciona pero si yo copio esto en un html y lo abro en mi navegador puedo ver el video.

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SV001my3nyU22DDBkcLR-UYA0l_jV1C8/preview" width="640" height="480" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

Comment: No puedo usar iFrame porque uso la etiqueta video directamente en mi reproductor HTML

Answer (score 0):

En la url del video en Google Drive obten el ID:

/1SV001my3nyU22DDBkcLR-UYA0l_jV1C8/

este id úsalo en tu página usando la url de Google Drive, recuerda que el
video debe estar compartido públicamente:

https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1SV001my3nyU22DDBkcLR-UYA0l_jV1C8

código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo Google Drive</title>
</head>
<body>
 <center><video id="video-google-drive" poster="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1SV001my3nyU22DDBkcLR-UYA0l_jV1C8" preload="auto" controls>
    <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1SV001my3nyU22DDBkcLR-UYA0l_jV1C8" type="video/mp4">    
</video>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Otra opción es obtener el código embebido del video desde Google Drive y agregarlo a tu página:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo Google Drive</title>
</head>
<body>
 <center>
 <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SV001my3nyU22DDBkcLR-UYA0l_jV1C8/preview" width="640" height="480" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```